Fantasy movie with a wife-killing contraption in a gladiator arena and some magic/force/something called 'the Way'
It came on on one of the like, three channels available in my cabin on a cruise ship I was on about four years back. I only saw maybe twenty minutes of it before I fell asleep, and I was deliriously tired for that twenty minutes. So I didn't really understand or remember anything that anyone was saying, but I remember the visuals. I'm pretty sure it was a movie, it felt more like one and there weren't any ad breaks, but I'm not 100% on that.
When it came on, it was in the middle of a gladiator-arena type scene. There was a construct in the center of the arena, where a bunch of dudes' wives (I mean I assumed they were wives not just random women) were chained up to a column. Suspended above them were giant sharp things on a hinge, held up by a chain. If the chain went slack, the sharp thing swung down and stabbed the wife through the chest. The other end of the chain was attached to the wife's respective dude. All of the guys are fighting each other, and if they lose their footing and let the weight of the chain drag them, wife gets stabbed through the gut and dies.
There was another scene after that, but I think it was mostly talking or didn't make sense without context because I can only vaguely remember it and not enough to describe it. There may or may not have been a horse.
At some point later there's a village thing in a desert-type place, I think. It might have been more 'sprawling city of tents' than village I'm not entirely sure. There was a woman involved. And a guy who seemed relatively important to the story. (After it moved from murder to conversations I was too tired to really grasp what was happening.)
Some kind of training scene happened where a new guy was trying to teach another guy (possibly important-guy) how to use 'the Way', which I think kind of let him connect to the world around him in a way that let him anticipate things before they happened in a fight? Not sure about that one. But it was definitely called 'the Way'. And may or may not have been a rip off of 'the Force'.
Then there were some important people who seemed vaguely villainous talking on what... might have been a spaceship? (I was really, really tired) I think they were standing by a big window. sounded like they were plotting. Or discussing a plot. It was an otherwise relatively empty room, that might have had metal-ish looking walls, but I'm not positive. It may have just been a setting in a wealthier environment, I'm not 100% on the spaceship thing, but there was a vaguely sci-fi-ish tone to the scene.
And then I fell asleep. I think it was taking place on a non-Earth planet, it felt pretty fantasy. There may have been a sci-fi element, if the maybe-spaceship was indeed a spaceship, but there wasn't obvious modern technology or anything. I think it looked fairly recent, but not super-recent. Around early 2000s, maybe a little before. It seemed like some kind of hero's journey story.
(From other peoples' suggestions on another site I've eliminated HBO's Rome (not that Roman), Caligula (not that old, not that Roman), Zardoz (not that old, or that tone), and Arena (less obvious technology, and the arena wasn't the main plot))

Welcome to Movies SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify when and where you saw that movie?

Sci-fi show Andromeda fits the overall description and also features people learning a Force-like religion called The Way (AKA Wayism), but I'm afraid I barely watched this show. Maybe someone else here (or over at Sci-Fi.SE) could pinpoint the exact episode?

Parts of this sound like Dune, except it was called 'The Weirding Way', but you do mentioned a 'desert-type place' and it being sci-fi already makes me think Dune right away. 
I don't remember there being a fight in an arena really but I haven't seen the movie in a few years. There was definitely a training scene with Paul learning the Weirding Way though. Great movie.

Great movie indeed, but without the arena scene.
